# Update table1 from table2

Tags: mysql, sql

table1:

```
|column1|column2|column3|

|data111|data222|data333|

|data444|data555|data666|
```

table2:

```
|column1|column2|

|empty11|empty22|
```

I need to update column1 and column2 in table2, but this query do nothing:

```
UPDATE table2, table1
    SET table2.column1 = table1.column1,
        table2.column2 = table1.column2
WHERE table1.column3 = 'data666'
```

After this query this message: 0 rows affected

Comment: What is/are the common key between the tables ?

Comment: i'm guessing there is only 1 record in table 2 and data444 and data555 have to be replaced by empty11 and empty22?

Comment: empty means no data in table2

Comment: If you are updating empty table then it always returns message i.e 0 rows affected. Update query simply update the table data not inserting the data if table is empty.

Comment: Ok, if I'm updating table with 1 record then only 1 record will update, right? So, how to update and add more records?

Comment: First of all you can add unique id columns to both tables. Then insert records in table using insert query.

Comment: Can't you just do: insert into table2 select table1.column1, table1.column2 from table1 WHERE table1.column3 = 'data666'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `INSERT` into table2 the wanted row(s) from table1:

```
insert into table2 (column1, column2)
    select column1, column2 from table1 
    where  table1.column3 = 'data666'
```

Comment: I was typing the same answer but u did it rather quickly +1

Comment: And then when I need update table2 - just delete all data and INSERT again, right? right))

Comment: Hard for us to say, since we don't know your system. Maybe the question is why store some rows (with same data) in two different tables?